# Determining if a point is inside a path element in Raphael.js

Tags: raphael

I have an SVG map and I want to draw some data using circles on the map. I want to make sure that the center of the circle drops inside the path. I can not use the bounding box, because yet it may be outside of the boundaries.

How can I determine if a point is inside a path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Raphael.isPointInsidePath()** - http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.isPointInsidePath